# Laravel 8 admin login not correctly redirecting

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, authorization

What am I missing here?
I've created an admin login, which should redirects to /admin-home. When I login, authorisation occurs, but Im being redirected to /login instead. If I go to /admin-home manually afterwards I am logged in, but not (re)directly..

web.php

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->middleware('auth')->name('login');
Route::get('/admin/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdminLoginController::class, 'showLoginForm']);
Route::post('/admin/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdminLoginController::class, 'adminLogin']);
```

AdminLoginController

```
class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
//...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.admin-login');
    }

    public function adminLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8|regex:/[a-z]/|regex:/[A-Z]/|regex:/[0-9]/',
        ]);


        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return redirect()->intended('/admin-home');
        }
        return view('/admin/login')->withInput($request->only('email'));
    }
```

admin-login.blade.php

```
            <form method="POST" action="/admin/login" name="frm_login" id="frm_login">
                @csrf
```

Comment: Right before redirecting, try adding `$request->session()->regenerate();` and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Nope.. no difference..

Comment: this could be nothing as well but see if `return redirect()->route('admin-home');` makes a difference.

Comment: Did you perhaps modify RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware?

Comment: If you could, please share the relevant code from the middleware too.

Comment: @user3532758, yes, redirect()->route('admin-home'); does it! Thank you!

Comment: Can you please vote for my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return redirect()->intended('/admin-home');
```

this works:

```
redirect()->route('admin-home');
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of this code

```
return redirect()->intended('/admin-home');
```

change this

```
return redirect()->intended('admin-home');
```

if not worked this to screen route which directing admin-home page

Comment: Doenst make a difference.. can you explain your last sentence? You mean I need to change something in web.php?

Comment: Route::get('/admin-home', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminPortalController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth:admin')->name('admin-home');

Comment: you wrote intended('/admin-home'). It is not correct. Because your route name admin-home. Therefore change this to intended('admin-home')  in AdminLoginController

Comment: Thank you, I did that. But the wrong redirecting still occurs..

Comment: @Samandar `intended` takes a path,  not a route name